# unable to Delete a Document in a view

Tags: xpages

I am working on an Intranet Page with several views and forms, but one of my views gives me a headache. In all views i use:

```
<xp:button value="delete documents" id="button1" >
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
<xp:this.action>
    <xp:deleteSelectedDocuments view="viewPanel1"
        message="Do you really want to delete these documents?">
    </xp:deleteSelectedDocuments>
</xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

to delete Selected Documents. But in one it does not work. Also when i try to use Code to delete them like:

```
var viewcontrol = getComponent("viewPanel1");
var ids = viewcontrol.getSelectedIds();
```

i dont get any Id's back from the view. The view is nothing special and i have full Access to the documents. Anyone who had this kind of trouble before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found my problem:](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpagesnodatavalidation.htm) Had to remove `immediate="true"`from the event handler or uncheck "Do not validate or update data" in the event Properties. Works fine now..